# Add a List<object> or Arraylist to an array of CustomObject[]

Tags: c#, arrays, list, object

I have tried many ways like
`Cast<CustomObject>`, `as Customobject` and `ToArray(Customobject)` but nothing worked.

How can I add `List` or `ArrayList` via AddRange to a `CustomObject[]` Array?

Code is really difficult.
But if you have some time you can get the complete source of the destination list from here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4012/C-List-View-v1-3?msg=3844172#xx3844172xx

This is a Custom Listview
I activated a combobox for the second column, so I can select diferrent values for a cell.
But before this, I have to add something to select.
This is the hole problem.

Update:
Firstly, thanks for the help !
Secondly, Found a solution in the comments from the website with the source.
Had to add some code and changed the destination custom array to a List

Comment: Are the `object`s in your `List<object>` instances of `CustomObject`? Because if they aren't, you can't do it.

Comment: Could you at some test code that you've used please?

Comment: Try breaking down the problem. What's the very bit of code where you add the items to the combo box? Breaking it down to a little piece of code may help you too.

Answer (score 6):

```
list.Cast<CustomObject>().ToArray()
```

Will work as long as the things in the list are actually `CustomObject`. If they might be other types, you can use `OfType<CustomObject>()` instead of `Cast`. This will filter out anything of an incompatible type.

Comment: @Rene You are welcome. If this solved your problem, please click the check mark next to the answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: In 4 minutes... (Wait time from tackoverflow)

Comment: Too fast, its not working... Says cannot convert string to GLSubItem, but if I only add one item (.Add("myString")) it works...

Comment: @Rene You should really show us some code to see what is wrong.

Comment: @Rene Sorry to hear that, but it is difficult to offer any suggestions based on the current question. If you update it to include some example code that reproduces your problem, that will make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `objects` really are instances of `CustomObject`, use LINQ `Select` method:

```
objList.Select(o => o as CustomObject).ToArray();
```

Otherwise you will get an array of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If its a `List<CustomObject>` then let us say

```
CustomObject[] coarr = list_of_customobject.ToArray();
```

If its an ArrayList then

```
CustomObject[] coarr = arraylist.OfType<CustomObject>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure whether all of your objects are of the type `CustomObject`  try

```
var result = list.OfType<CustomObject>.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking you cannot *add* elements to an array, since an array's length remains constant over its lifetime. There are two things you can do:

**Create a new array**

```
myArray = myTList.ToArray() // generic)
myArray = myArrayList.Cast<CustomObject>().ToArray() // cast, non-generic
myArray = myArrayList.OfType<CustomObject>().ToArray() // filter by type, non-generic
```

**Set elements of an array**

```
myArray[x] = myTList[y] // generic
myArray[x] = (CustomObject)myArrayList[y] // non-generic
```

I recommend you to take the generic collection whenever possible. They provide you additional type safety. Casting `object` variables cause runtime errors you could detect at compile time by using generic types.

If you actually want to *add* elements to an existing collection, you may try to use a dynamic collection type rather than an array: `List<T> : IList<T>` or `LinkedList<T> : ICollection<T>` are a good point to start, or maybe more specific types like `Stack<T>` or `Queue<T>`.